# Fedora 26 freezes and crashes after update

Tags: linux, fedora

I am using a Lenovo Thinkpad T540p. It worked well with Fedora 25. Since an upgrade to Fedora 26, the system freezes whenever I try to change from a tty to GUI or try to shut down (both using console and GUI). My system is up-to-date. This does not occur when running Fedora 26 from a Live USB stick.

Today, the laptop also suddenly started crashing (i. e. it suddenly turned off) with no information left in the logs. The laptop did not overheat and had enough power left in the battery. I am not able to reproduce this, however.

This is the output `journalctl -b -p err` of a complete session in between two of such freezes:

```
Jul 29 17:39:36 lappy kernel: Error parsing PCC subspaces from PCCT
Jul 29 17:39:36 lappy kernel: ACPI Error: Needed type [Reference], found [Integer] ffff998eb44e0168 (20170119/exresop-103)
Jul 29 17:39:36 lappy kernel: ACPI Exception: AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE, While resolving operands for [OpcodeName unavailable] (20170119/dswexec-461)
Jul 29 17:39:36 lappy kernel: ACPI Error: Method parse/execution failed [\_PR.CPU0._PDC] (Node ffff998eb5cf1a78), AE_AML_OPERAND_TYPE (20170119/psparse-543)
Jul 29 17:39:36 lappy systemd-modules-load[252]: Failed to find module 'vboxdrv'
Jul 29 17:39:36 lappy systemd-modules-load[252]: Failed to find module 'vboxnetflt'
Jul 29 17:39:36 lappy systemd-modules-load[252]: Failed to find module 'vboxnetadp'
Jul 29 17:39:36 lappy systemd-modules-load[252]: Failed to find module 'vboxpci'
Jul 29 17:39:37 lappy kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: priv: HUB0: 085014 ffffffff (1d70820b)
Jul 29 17:39:37 lappy kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: priv: GPC0: 4188ac 00000001 (1870822e)
Jul 29 17:39:37 lappy kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: Pointer to TMDS table invalid
Jul 29 17:39:37 lappy kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: Pointer to flat panel table invalid
Jul 29 17:39:53 lappy kernel: tpm tpm0: A TPM error (6) occurred attempting to read a pcr value
Jul 29 17:40:00 lappy avahi-daemon[1001]: chroot.c: open() failed: No such file or directory
Jul 29 17:40:20 lappy libvirtd[1149]: Could not find keytab file: /etc/libvirt/krb5.tab: No such file or directory
Jul 29 17:40:44 lappy spice-vdagent[1589]: Cannot access vdagent virtio channel /dev/virtio-ports/com.redhat.spice.0
Jul 29 17:41:21 lappy spice-vdagent[2025]: Cannot access vdagent virtio channel /dev/virtio-ports/com.redhat.spice.0
```

Maybe it is an issue with the nouveau driver?

Sometimes I am able to catch error messages when trying to shut down, once it was logged (the other times those error messages were not logged)

```
Jul 29 16:49:41 lappy kernel: nouveau 0000:01:00.0: DRM: failed to idle channel 0 [DRM]
Jul 29 17:25:34 lappy kernel: INFO: rcu_sched detected stalls on CPUs/tasks:
Jul 29 17:25:34 lappy kernel:         4-...: (1 GPs behind) idle=5f5/140000000000000/0 softirq=41973/41973 fqs=14341 
Jul 29 17:25:34 lappy kernel:         (detected by 6, t=60003 jiffies, g=61506, c=61505, q=0)
Jul 29 17:25:34 lappy kernel: NMI watchdog: Watchdog detected hard LOCKUP on cpu 4
Jul 29 17:27:38 lappy systemd[1]: systemd-logind.service: Watchdog timeout (limit 3min)!
Jul 29 17:28:34 lappy kernel: INFO: rcu_sched detected stalls on CPUs/tasks:
Jul 29 17:28:34 lappy kernel:         4-...: (1 GPs behind) idle=5f5/140000000000000/0 softirq=41973/41973 fqs=57419 
Jul 29 17:28:34 lappy kernel:         (detected by 2, t=240008 jiffies, g=61506, c=61505, q=0)
```

Since this error does not occur when running from a live medium, I assume something went wrong with the update and not that my hardware is necessarily damaged. How can I further investigate and hopefully fix this issue?

The first processor given from `cat /proc/cpuinfo`:

```
processor   : 0
vendor_id   : GenuineIntel
cpu family  : 6
model       : 60
model name  : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4700MQ CPU @ 2.40GHz
stepping    : 3
microcode   : 0x22
cpu MHz     : 1519.189
cache size  : 6144 KB
physical id : 0
siblings    : 8
core id     : 0
cpu cores   : 4
apicid      : 0
initial apicid  : 0
fpu     : yes
fpu_exception   : yes
cpuid level : 13
wp      : yes
flags       : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm epb tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid xsaveopt dtherm ida arat pln pts
bugs        :
bogomips    : 4788.89
clflush size    : 64
cache_alignment : 64
address sizes   : 39 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
power management:
```

I am happy to give any additional information, if necessary.

Comment: does not look like crash to me. I would try to get rid of the virtualbox stuff

Answer (score 2):

@Zollem There is indeed a problem with `nouveau`. I had the exact same issue when trying to upgrade from 24 to 26. You need to install a new version of the nvidia driver. There are many steps to follow, so I will just post a guide here. I worked like a charm for me:

https://www.if-not-true-then-false.com/2015/fedora-nvidia-guide/